# Connect from Oracle server to MS SQL Server in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, jdbc

I have a Java application that is connecting to a MS SQL Server database using the Microsoft JDBC Driver 3.0 for SQL Server (sqljdbc.jar). The Java version this is being compiled to is 1.5.0_12. It is working fine from my local Windows machine, but it is causing all kinds of errors when I try to run it from the Oracle server. Any advice as to how to make that successful connection?

Comment: Can you give an example of the errors? Is it a jvm version issue?

Comment: Also tell the oracle jar you're using and the connection string

Comment: Oracle server? Do you mean Oracle application server?

Comment: My connection string is this:
java.sql.Connection con = null; 
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"; 
String serverName = "DEVTS***\\INST**"; 
String databaseName = "dms_cc_conversion"; 
String userName = "****"; 
String password = "*************"; 
String connectionUrl = url + serverName + ";DatabaseName=" + databaseName ;
try {Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, userName, password);

Comment: Yes it is an Oracle application server. What Oracle jar (could this be my dumb mistake)?

Comment: One of the errors I am getting when it runs from the server is "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: testing"

It runs on my local computer so I do not know where the ClassCastException is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

** Withdrawn... Sorry, didn't see the Application Server portion in the initial question

Comment: I am not connecting to Oracle. I am running the code from an Oracle server and trying to connect to MS SQL Server.